# Чи є різниця між "хутровий" та "хутряний"?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

За Академічним тлумачним словником обидва слова мають сему:

> з хутра (у 3 знач.), на хутрі.

Як показує тлумачний словник СУМ, обидва слова також є прикметниками від **хутро**.
Диференційну сему спостерігаємо в слові "хутровий":

> Пов'язаний з добуванням, обробкою й продажем хутра.

Чи є тоді різниця у словосполученнях **хутровий одяг** та **хутряний одяг**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На це питання лапідарно відповідає сайт [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/xutrovuj-i-xutryanuj)
[image]

> ***Хутровий*** – пов'язаний із розведенням звірів, добуванням та обробкою
>   хутра, а також з торгівлею хутром: хутровий звір, хутровий ринок,
>   хутрова промисловість.
>
> ***Хутряний*** – виготовлений, пошитий із хутра: хутряний комір, хутряний
>   одяг, хутряна шапка, хутряні рукавиці.

Тобто, правильно вживати саме ***хутряний одяг***, а не ***хутровий одяг***.

Comment: Дякую, натомість мене збиває той факт, що **хутровий** відноситься до виробів ( на картинці маємо у першому стовпчику *вироби*), а одяг, шапка, рукавиці - це свого роду теж вироби, результат промисловості. Може я просто залізла в дебрі :)